# how to extract only server names in c#

Tags: c#

i want to extract only server names which is starting from `\\`.  `\\` is removed.  After extracting server names this string is parsed. how can i do?

Answer (score 5):

Look at the Uri class.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\Myserver\myshare\myfile.txt");
uri.Host == "Myserver"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:  `\\\\.*?\\`